# Sorting a column in descending order in R excluding the first row

Tags: r, sorting, row

I have a dataframe with 5 columns and a very large dataset. I want to sort by column 3. How do you sort everything after the first row? (When calling this function I want to end it with nrows)

Example output:

Original:

```
4
7
9
6
8
```

New:

```
4
9
8
7
6
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm correctly understanding what you want to do, this approach should work:

```
z <- data.frame(x1 = seq(10), x2 = rep(c(2,3), 5), x3 = seq(14, 23))
zsub <- z[2:nrow(z),]
zsub <- zsub[order(-zsub[,3]),]
znew <- rbind(z[1,], zsub)
```

Basically, snip off the rows you want to sort, sort them in descending order on column 3, then reattach the first row.

And here's a piped version using `dplyr`, so you don't clutter the workspace with extra objects:

```
library(dplyr)
z <- z %>%
    slice(2:nrow(z)) %>%
    arrange(-x3) %>%
    rbind(slice(z, 1), .)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try this single line of code to modify the third column in your data frame `df` as described:

```
df[,3] <- c(df[1,3],sort(df[-1,3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df$x[-1] <- df$x[-1][order(df$x[-1], decreasing=T)]
#   x
# 1 4
# 2 9
# 3 8
# 4 7
# 5 6
```